# How to Select the value duplicated the least number of times in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with the columns

FacilityID, servername

with the facilityID being the primary key and the servername being the server that the data for that facility is located on.

When we add a new facility, I want to be able to select the servername used the least number of times, but I am not sure how to do that.

I am thinking it will use the count function, but I am unsure of the syntax involved.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your DBMS? Is there support for Windowed AGgregate Functions or TOP/LIMIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on database, in mssql i would do:

```
select top 1  FacilityID,count(servername) over (partition by FacilityID) as Cardinality from tablename order by Cardinality asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the COUNT and then outside the MIN.

```
Select MIN (x.myCount )
FROM (
  select COUNT (servername) as myCount 
  from ...
  GROUP BY servername) as x
```

Comment: Few errors here...need to alias subquery, need a group by on facilityID not servername, missing group by in main clause with min count, and query will return full list of all facilityID's and their counts, not just the one with least.

Comment: yep, sorry, I just wrote it from my mind. You could also add the HAVING outside so it will only display the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
    SELECT servername, COUNT() Cnt
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY servername
)
ORDER BY Cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * TOP 1 
FROM (
    Select servername , Count(FacilityID) as Count
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY FacilityID
    ORDER BY Count ASC)
```